# Bind Variable Amount of Parameters in Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm currently trying to build a little generic function to make inserts. My goal is to pass the table, the columns, values and types to fullfill an insert.

My only problem is the statement:

```
$stmt -> bind_param($types, $var1, $var2 ...);
```

What i would basically need is something like this:

```
$stmt -> bind_param($types, $array);
```

This is what i got till now:

```
function insert($into, $columns, $values, $types) {
    global $connection;

    // Check Correct Length
    if(count($columns) != count($values) ||
       count($columns) != count($types)) {
           return false;
       }

    $count = count($columns);

    $column_string = "";
    $value_string = "";
    $value_types = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $column_string .= $columns[$i];
        $value_types .= $types[$i];

        $value_string .= '?';

        if($i + 1 < $count) {
            $column_string .= ',';
            $value_string .= ',';
        }
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $into ($column_string) VALUES ($value_string)";

    // Execute Statement
    if($stmt = $connection -> prepare($sql)) {

        // $stmt -> bind_param("sss", $transaction, $email, $status);
        // What to do here?

        $stmt -> execute();

        $stmt -> close();
    }
```

The SQL statement already looks fine. Also the types are ready - i just need a way to dynamically bind the parameters...

Comment: You can't. `bindparam` is a 1:1 mapping. You could use the array option in execute() to pass in everything at once. `$stmt->execute(array(':foo' => 'bar', ....));`

Comment: can you give me some more information on that? Is there a negative side of doing it like this?

Comment: well, this only helps for executing a query. if you're wanting to bind result values, you're stuck with many bindparam() calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well I assume, that in *$columns* is defined as `$columns = array('col1', 'col2'/*...*/);` and *$values* as `$values = array($val1, $val2/*...*/);`

I would create function for column names escaping.

`$escapeCols = function($column) {
    return sprintf('`%s`', $column);
};`

Another function for creating *? placeholders*

`$placeholders = function ($values) {
    return array_fill(0, count($values), '?');
}`

You can than prepare query

`$sql = sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)',
    $table,
    implode(', ', array_map($escapeCols, $columns),
    implode(', ', $placeholders($values))
);`

And then you can call [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

`$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($values);`

This way can be easily transformed if you would have *$values* defined as

`$values = array('col1' => $va1, 'col2' => $val2);`

Comment: First of all Thanks - i tried this but receive the following error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/virtual/.../helper.php on line 126

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed you are using *mysqli*. My comment would work on *pdo*. Which has imho better capabilities.